# Take the repeating substring in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a string in Python like the following:

```
str = "Surname:.......1 of 10 Surname:........2 of 10 Surname.........3 of 10............."
```

I want to take every substring of the form:

`"Surname:.......<number> of 10"`

and edit it.

How could I take the n (above is 10) substrings that starts and end with the same form?
I have tried the following :

```
    str = 'Surname:mike 1 of 3 Surname:uknown of 3 Surname:little 3 of 3'
    x = re.findall("Surname:.*[0-9]*\s*of", str)
    print(x)
```

but the result is :

```
['Surname:mike 1 of 3 Surname:uknown of 3 Surname:little 3 of 3']
```

and I want something like this :

```
['Surname:mike 1 of 3','Surname:unkown 2 of 3','Surname:little 3 of 3']
```

Of course I think there is a solution to iterate through the string but firstly I want to see if there is another solution with less code.

Comment: [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) looks only for the first hit. Use re.match() instead. In case it is still not working, please show us your regex and the code how you applied the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, regex in python matches the largest possible thing.  Add a `?` to make it take the smallest possible thing:

```
x = re.findall("Surname:.*?[0-9]*\s*of", str)
```

The `*?` matches the smallest possible sequence of zero or more things, whereas `*` matches the largest possible sequence